# Calling .focus() on a text field during a jquery-ui dialog-with-tabs load breaks the dialog rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I use

```
setTimeout(function{$('#myElement').focus()}, 10)`
```

during the loading of a jquery-ui dialog containing tabs, the rendering of the tabs breaks! Specifically, their background images fail to appear which makes them look like garbage. This ONLY happens when I set a timeout on document ready to focus the first text input in the popup.

This behavior is bizarre. Thoughts?

Note: This only happens in firefox and opera.

Comment: You responded with a stock response that failed to address the problem. I was shorthanding the notation, but I failed to mention that.

Comment: Stock response......well if you gave a proper description and maybe a demo url replicating the issue it might lead to a better solution...

Comment: you do know the dialog auto attempts to set focus to the first visible input

Comment: see http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4731

Comment: so you have a tabbed interface inside the dialog. Are the tabs loading the content using xhr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a classic concurrency problem to me. You're altering the code while jQuery's working on it, and that's probably breaking some assumption in the code that the state of the DOM will stay stable.

If you want to focus a textfield after the dialog is loaded, the proper way to do it is to put your focus() in a callback method.

Also, do you really mean to wait for 10 **milliseconds** and then focus()?

Comment: The wait is a an arbitrary fix for ie6/7. Calling focus directly does not work.

Comment: This may be the solution. Doing prelim testing.

Comment: Solid insight. I added a callback and whammo. WORKS! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error?

Are you sure the element is in the dom and visible thus focusable when the function is invoked.

Does increasing the timeout value fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying your code directly, it could just be that you forgot the () after focus.

```
setTimeout($('#myElement').focus(), 10);
```

Comment: that would just cause the focus to invoke instantly rather than in 10 milliseconds